Very poor communication by most of my colleagues
I work full time as a senior software engineer as a contractor for a 10 person tech company which is remote-only. All communication is text-only with the exception of twice-a-week audio meetings.
Some of the issues I have noticed with communication are:

People will just PM me some random logs with a "?", no details added. I obviously don't want to waste an hour trying to figure out what they mean by analysing the logs. When I ask them follow-up questions, they stop replying.

People will just ask me a question with a one line statement with no background context added. I have tried answering with very little info. This person didn't clarify or thank me. Later during a meeting, he didn't point fingers but he complained that he is struggling with the codebase.

Junior developers will ask me questions. When I answer them, they never reply and tell me if it worked or not. Sometimes, I waste a lot of time finding a solution and then they are like "oh, the first solution already worked, I don't need help anymore".

If you ask someone something, sometimes they don't reply and leave you on read forever.

Please or thank you or even hi are words no one ever uses.


I can live without thank you or greetings. I am a contractor and more interested in being productive and collecting my invoices. But it  does affect my productivity. What should I do?

And when you raised those points with your manager/boss they've said...?

@AidaPaul I have not raised these issue with my manager yet. I am still trying to decide what's the best course of action. I don't want to be seem like a whiner.

I am not sure how asking about culture makes someone a whiner. How many other contractors in that company?

These individuals you describe.  Are they also contractors or employees of the company?  What does your contract say about offering support in this capacity? What does the individual, responsible for formally tasking you on behalf of the company, have to say about this topic? You are a contractor and work for the company, at the end of the day, if the company wants to pay you to answer these questions that is their decision. While it sucks from a human perspective not to show your appreciation, at the end of the day answering these questions appear to be what you have been contracted to answer

@AidaPaul How it's a work culture related? Any sane person would agree that greetings like Hi/Please/Thanks are polite. Same about communication. It's just a bad habit, many people in the company have.

@Donald I don't know about other people contract. My contract is not very detailed and I don't mind helping colleagues as part of my work (but prefer clear communication instead of so vague, cryptic messages).

@CodePanda you are making it a bit hard to help you, so I'll bow out, for the sake of my sanity.

@CodePanda - You didn't answer my question, these individuals asking for assistance, are they contractors or full-time employees of the company?

@CodePanda Why do you think it's not related to work culture? Communication norms are key to a company's culture; they shape how people interact, collaborate, and feel at work. I think you should raise your concerns with your manager.

@Donald Yes. I did "I don't know about other people contract". I don't know if they are full-time or contractors.

@AidaPaul See the first statement of Pete B's answer. I 100% agree with it. That's why I want to stay invisible.

@n.bennett See the first statement of Pete B's answer. I 100% agree with it. That's why I want to stay invisible.

It might be helpful to have an idea of the region in which the company and/or employees are based, as national/local culture inevitably influences work cultures.

The comments on this can't-help-because-poor-communication question have gone weirdly meta.

"How it's a work culture related? Any sane person would agree that greetings like Hi/Please/Thanks are polite." That's absolutely culture related. Your culture considers that polite and the right thing to do, but in other cultures that's just unnecessary padding and people just want to get to the point. Where I live and work, people rarely say "hi" or "please" in text (especially in chat). They get straight to the point. It's not rude here (if anything, wasting time with unnecessary politeness is considered rude).

About this "All communication is text-only with the exception of twice-a-week audio meetings."  Is this a company policy or just what is usually done?  Are you really prohibited from calling a person (or asking them to call you) to get details?  I'm not necessarily suggesting you do that.  I'm just trying to understand the boundaries any solution needs to work within.

As a contractor you are always a bit on the outs.  You will lose any HR type disagreements with a fulltime employee.  It is the nature of the work.  So you have to be careful here.
Since it is not your responsibility to train or make others productive (only that you are productive), the path is clear here.  For numbers 1, 2 and 3 I would reply with a "what have you tried?" or "can you "clarify your issue?".  Those kinds of follow up questions are reasonable and something I would expect from a person that I was seeking help from.
Think about the times you need help, what do you do?  You might provide the log file, and any background information with the issue you are having.  This is the right way to handle an information request.  What you are experiencing is asocial behavior, not harmful but not social.
Once they do not respond the responsibility becomes theirs not yours.  And if your company saves text chat logs, you have documentation that you did what you were supposed to do.
IMHO staying out of all the HR crap is a massive benefit of being a contractor.  Being a productive contractor often helps you survive layoffs and downsizing.   Managers tend to like the work being done without the drama.
If a coworker does ask for an information request that will prove to be a lengthy investigation, ask your manager for guidance about how he would like you to spend your time.

Thank you very much. It's a very good answer. I want to stay away from drama and focus on my work, and I will do that

(FWIW, it's often possible to stay away from drama even as an employee.)

I've also seen contractors be the first to go in downsizing as they were perceived as "more expensive" but without the the disadvantage of having to pay any redundancy (UK)

I think asocial would be a better term than antisocial, antisocial behaviour is harmful

Agree with @ScottishTapWater, antisocial behavior is behavior that actively harms others like harassment, not just failing to communicate - https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/asb/asb/antisocial-behaviour/what-is-antisocial-behaviour/

"You will lose any HR type disagreements with a fulltime employee." I don't think it is that black-and-white, but you are at a disadvantage, yes.

Agree with Pete's suggestion of replying with "what have you tried?" I used to ask quite a few questions of a senior engineer at one place I worked, and his attitude was to take a Socratic approach, answering my questions with questions that would lead me to finding the solution myself.  With time I found this both so annoying and also helpful that I got into the habit of finding solutions myself.  Perhaps you can engender this culture among the junior engineers you refer to.

replying with "what have you tried?" - honestly: I'd kind of start treating that like StackOverflow Questions. Log with just a "?" -> A:"Need more info", then "close". If they need help, they need to ask an answerable question.

@Fildor "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence" straight from the how to ask page.

With regards to "And if your company saves text chat logs", last year, the company that I contract with instigated a policy of purging chat logs after 2 weeks.  It sure makes it great that I can say anything I like and know it will be long gone by the time lawyers are involved.  But if I don't get around to using some information in a timely manner, it's also gone.

@PeterM I guess I figured that a chat between 2 people would vanish as soon as both of them closed their view of it. If I knew everything I wrote was going somewhere, it would slow my responses considerably. Do they record conversations in offices and hallways too? Why not, could be useful...

As a contractor, you're more than likely being treated as a disposable resource and a bit of an outsider.  People also can be resentful that you're being paid more than a regular employee (even when you're not).
It's perfectly reasonable for you to ask for more information when being asked for information.


People will just PM me some random logs with a "?". No details added. I obviously don't want to waste 1 hour trying to figure out what they mean by analysing the logs. When I ask them follow-up questions, they stop replying.


In these cases, just ask for the additional information/context that you need to investigate further.  If no information is forthcoming, assume that the query isn't all that important and just carry on with your work.


People will just ask me question with 1-line statement with no background context added. I tried to answer with very little info. This person didn't clarify or thanked me. Later during meeting, he didn't point fingers but he complained that he is struggling with codebase.


Same as above.  If there's any come-back on your calls, just point out that additional information will result in appropriate help.


Junior developers will ask me questions. When I answer them, they never reply and tell me if it worked or not. Sometime, I waste lot of time finding solution and then there are like "oh, the first solution already worked, I don't need help anymore".


Be as helpful as you reasonably can be with the new developers.  They sometimes don't know any different, so hopefully leading by example will rub off on them and they'll learn how to communicate and team-work as a result of your interactions.  It might not pan out that way of course, but it's a start.


If you ask someone something, sometime they don't reply and leave you on read forever.


If non-response is affecting your work, then follow up after a day or so and tell the respondent (or more accurately, non-respondent) that this open question is holding up the project. At least then you've got something in writing and you're showing you're not really willing to sit by and not be answered to.


Please or thank you or even hi are words no one ever uses.


This shouldn't stop you from saying Hi/Please/Thankyou of course.

Regarding (5), in some cases it should stop you from saying hi/please/thank you. See some of the other questions here where people are complaining about coworkers using excessive/unnecessary pleasantries in messages!

@Esther I think the pleasantries have just evolved.  "Hi" should not be a separate message, but it doesn't cause trouble as the first word of a chat message posing a question.  "Thanks" and "bye" can be combined into one reaction (e.g. "Thumbs up" on MS Teams) so that the interaction feels human enough.

@Esther - It's all down to context I think.  I always try to be polite and appear friendly to co-workers because I know it can make a difference to people's sense of inclusion, especially when contractors and off-shore colleagues are habitually being treated as assets rather than people.


All communication is text-only with the exception of twice-a-week audio meetings.

The main problem seems to be that your coworkers don't know how to communicate properly in writing (or they don't bother). One of their main way of not communicating properly is that they just stop replying.
But you have twice-a-week audio meetings!
Here is a suggestion.
Keep a file or folder in your computer in which you copy-paste all these unfinished demands for help. That includes everything covered by bullets 1-4 of your list.
When the next audio meeting comes, make a point of going through all the unfinished demands one by one.
Don't do this in a confrontational way. Frame it as if you are truly trying to help. Which you are.
Pros

This will force your coworkers to either clarify the issue, or explicitly tell you that they have already found a solution. They won't be able to just stop answering, since this is a real-time audio meeting.
If a coworker really needs your help but really lacks the skills to communicate with you in writing, you will be able to help that coworker much more easily this way.
If a coworker doesn't want you to bring up their demands during the audio meeting, they will naturally learn that when you ask them for clarification in PM discussions, "stop replying" is not a good strategy.
You will be a lot less stressed/distracted by these written communication issues, since you know that they will get resolved at the next meeting.
You will look like a reliable team-player that really cares about what everyone is working on and what issues everyone is facing.

Cons

There is a risk your coworkers will think the meetings always drag longer because of you.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is not what a lot of software engineers (myself included) like to hear, but you but you need it to improve your team's social dynamic so they see each other more as people and less like Chinese Rooms. This is especially important as you are all remote.
Push for daily standups and retrospectives -
Standups can be shorter and possibly replace the twice a week audio calls. But frequent shorter communication is better. Apart from more frequent occasions to raise issues, it also gives more interaction time between the team. I'm aware its not necessarily your job to sort out the meetings, but as its affecting your team's productivity its worth raising it as a suggestion to the team lead.
Reply the cryptic messages with a call -
Its much easier to get to the bottom of a problem verbally. It also has the affect of appearing responsive and helpful while discouraging raising trivial issues with you. Calls do mean you have less written records if you are concerned about your productivity being used against you then write a short summary in chat after the call
Turn your camera on in the audio calls -  it helps build a connection, even if it means you need to brush your hair in the morning.
Most Software Engineers tend to be dismissive of team building, but you don't need big team bonding events to improve the social dynamic, just being more present and visible is usually enough

+1 for calling back, as that will also increase the cost of asking. But there are probably good reasons for twice-weekly meetings instead of daily ones.

Maybe it's me, but I don't understand why calling back would discourage questions or increase the cost of asking. Unless your colleagues are completely antisocial. Seems helpful to me.

@Fe2O3 OK, and if their phone rings and someone tells them the answer then they're still getting an answer so that's still a win isn't it? How does that put them off asking questions?

@Rup what can be resolved in 1-5 minutes by text, will take at least 5-10 minutes in a call. The information is also completely transient, so if any of the people in the call needs to remember what it was (say, a week down the line or more), they have to make a new call. It's also completely confined to only the people in the call, you can't easily share the solution or decisions or whatever needed to be discussed with others after the discussion. Thus leading to more and more calls to re-clarify or fix any misconceptions. So now a 1-5 minute text solution turns into hours of calls over time

@VLAZ Faster based on what? If we're trying to debug something over text then maybe they explain it wrong because they missed the point, or send me the wrong logs, and I have to try and explain what they've done wrong so they can try again. It's going to take longer just to understand the problem. And typing is slower than talking, On a call they can share their screen so I've got complete information and we can work through it together, which is a better learning experience too.

@Fe2O3 The question was more about junior developers not communicating issues clearly,  and op not getting any context or closure on issues. Evidently getting information out of the junior developers via messaging is not working, a quick call can absolutely help there

@Fe2O3 I don't think its unreasonable to assume points 1 and 2 were also junior devs. Even if they are not, replacing "Junior Developers" with "Developers" doesn't change the sentiment of my comment

I am faculty at a research university. A lot of your frustration reminds me of teaching during COVID, when most of my peer-to-peer interactions with students were through Slack and email.
It certainly does not sound like this "fully remote" company has figured out, or even tried to figure out, how to establish appropriate work culture among their remote team (all the more successful fully-remote companies I work with spend considerable time and money on team building, to periodically remind their staff that they are actually a team, not just a bunch of individuals in front of a nameless Slack screen). However, this isn't likely to be something that you as a contractor can fix. The only thing you can do is work with the environment you are given (or look for a different appointment).
The good news is that, at least in my experience, being more explicit about what you expect or hope for can already go a long way:

People will just PM me some random logs with a "?". No details added. I obviously don't want to waste 1 hour trying to figure out what they mean by analysing the logs. When I ask them follow-up questions, they stop replying.

Normally, when people stop replying, it means that their problem is solved. Ask them after a while if they still struggle with that. If they say no, or if they don't answer, consider the issue resolved.

People will just ask me question with 1-line statement with no background context added.

Ask for clarifications. If no clarifications are forthcoming, then see the previous answer.

I tried to answer with very little info. This person didn't clarify or thanked me. Later during meeting, he didn't point fingers but he complained that he is struggling with codebase.

Unless your job is explicitly to help this person with this codebase, this does not sound like a you-problem. Don't make other people's problems yours (unless they are, of course).

Junior developers will ask me questions. When I answer them, they never reply and tell me if it worked or not. Sometime, I waste lot of time finding solution and then there are like "oh, the first solution already worked, I don't need help anymore".

Take a page out of standard support staff cookbooks and always end your answers with a polite "please let me know if your issue is resolved or if you need additional help". If no response is forthcoming, see the first item.

If you ask someone something, sometime they don't reply and leave you on read forever.

Send a reminder. Send another reminder. After that, if it's a blocking issue, escalate to your manager.
(also, don't take it as a personal insult every time somebody "leaves you on read" - people are busy, and sometimes people forget ... it happens even in a well-functioning team)

Please or thank you or even hi are words no one ever uses.

Well, that certainly sucks, but as you say it's not really a blocking issue. Try to see it more as a cultural thing, indeed in some teams (even fairly functional ones) chat-based communication is very to-the-point. I completely understand if you find this impolite (I would do), but maybe it's something you can learn to live with.
Overall, one idea I would strongly suggest is to do more one-on-one face-to-face meetings (for example, via Zoom or Teams). For example, if people send you a strange log without too much additional info, rather than asking for clarifications you can offer to just jump into a Zoom call with them, look at the issue together, and discuss follow-up questions directly. My experience is that working online, synchronously on an issue is often not only more effective than purely asynchronous communication, it also leads to future asynchronous communications becoming much more targeted.

@Fe2O3 I don't agree. There is a difference between being a good colleague and trying to be helpful even if people communicate poorly, and making other people's problem yours. Stubbornly refusing to help until you get a well-formed question is the former, taking responsibility for other people's lack of familiarity with the codebase is the latter (again, assuming that training on that codebase isn't part of the work assignment OP gets paid for).

@Fe2O3 Also, my answer explicitly says that OP should ask for follow-up once or twice, but then move on. To me that's not taking responsibility for the issue, that's just trying to be helpful in an environment that's not great.
